# NodeJS wrong final block length when decrypting string from Android app

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt in node.js an encrypted text string from an android app. The code that does the encryption is as follows.

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("MY_KEY".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
byte[] iv = "MY_IV".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
return String.format("%s", toBase64(cipherText));
```

I try do decrypt it with the following code.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var messageToDecrypt = Buffer.from(encryptedMessage, "base64");
var key = Buffer.from("MY_KEY", "utf8");
var iv = Buffer.from("MY_IV", "utf8");
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
var clearText = decipher.update(messageToDecrypt, 'base64', 'utf-8');
clearText += decipher.final("utf-8");
return clearText.trim();
```

However, I get `Error: error:1C80006B:Provider routines::wrong final block length` when applying `final("utf-8")`. No problem if I decrypt it with Android or Python. I'm using node.js 18.16.0 LTS.

Comment: The NodeJS code works for me with consistent data (tested with v18.12.1). Either the issue is version specific or it's due to the data. Check with a different version, post sample data.

Comment: Even with 18.16.0 LTS this cannot be reproduced. Post test data please.

Comment: How long is "MY_KEY"? Key suppose to a key, not password (learn the difference plz).